# Add Twilio numbers into "messaging service" via API

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I have a Twilio number that I want to add into my Twilio "messaging service" via the API.

[image]

Example request (that doesn't work):

```
$add_number = $twilio->account->incoming_phone_numbers->create(array(
    "PhoneNumber" => $number,
    "MessagingServiceSid" => "MG68f3...4b72", // Messaging Service ID on Twilio
));
```

[The Twilio API docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers) only seem to mention `SmsApplicationSid` which doesn't achieve the outcome I want.

I want to be able to add existing numbers (that I've already purchased) into my messaging service, and when I buy new numbers be able to add those into the messaging service at the same time.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Unfortunately at the time or writing you can't create messaging services via the API. The same goes for associating numbers. To do that you will need to go via the [console](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/messaging/services) and add them manually.

The page [Sending Messages with Copilot](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages-copilot) shows you how to use an existing messaging service though.

Hope this helps.

Comment: On [the page you referenced above](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages-copilot#add-phone-number) it seems like you *can* add existing numbers to existing messaging services, based on the example: `$twilio->messaging->v1->services("...")->phoneNumber->create("...");`, yet when I try this using the latest Twilio SDK version (`~5.9`) I see this error: `Unknown domain messaging`. Am I misunderstanding your answer possibly?

Comment: Hey Marcos. Has this changed since?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is a way to add a phone number to the A2P Messaging service via API now.  From their documentation:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/api/phonenumber-resource#create-a-phonenumber-resource-add-a-phone-number-to-a-messaging-service

```
phone_number = client.messaging \
                 .v1 \
                 .services('MGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') \
                 .phone_numbers \
                 .create(
                      phone_number_sid='PNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
                  )
```